# Local Variable On Stack(C)

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, stack

I know Assembly and C and I wanted to try something. I compiled with **GCC** this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1()
{
    int a=1, b=2, c=3;
};

void f2()
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf ("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
};

int main()
{
    f1();
    f2();
};
```

I know how stack works in assembly and as I know the expected output should be 1,2,3 (Because this is the "Garbage" on the Stack).

The output in https://www.onlinegdb.com/ is 1,2,3
but when I compile it on my gcc(in windows, version 6.3.0) the output is: 3, 6422352, 4200832

if I will change f1 to:

```
void f1()
{
    int a=1, b=2, c=3,d=4,e=5;
};
```

the output will be 3,4,5 (like it skips the 1 and 2).

why is that?

**EDIT: BEFORE ANSWERING READ THIS!!**

of course I know that C\CPP generate garbage and it can be anything.
I am talking about the assembly side, if you dont know assembly or dont know how stack works please dont answer.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.  There is no point in expecting a certain value to result.

Comment: Neither the C language nor any flavor of assembly has an answer for you. Presumably you could find an answer to why you observe this particular manifestation of undefined behavior in this particular case by disassembling the program or perhaps by studying GCC's source closely enough.  My guess, though, would be that the call to `f1()` is inlined (but not altogether eliminated), whereas the call to `f2()` is not.

Comment: Turn off all optimizations and try again.

Comment: This is wrong: "*I know the expected output should be 1,2,3*". There is no expected output in this code snippet.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie without optimizations: -O0 gives the same result and -O or -Og gives 0,0,0

Comment: @Shay You can't say why it may or may not work because try this - https://onlinegdb.com/Bk4UuaqbD   Tell me how?

Comment: 1,2,3 _could_ remain as garbage on the stack or not. Garbage is garbage.

Comment: *"I am talking about the assembly side, if you dont know assembly or dont know how stack works please dont answer."* - The compiler is free to generate any assembly code as long as the observable behavior stays the same. So it's pretty pointless to ask why this happened. Of course we can speculate, but no matter the reason, you cannot rely on it.

Comment: If you want to see the assembly code, just compile with `-S`

Comment: Since you know assembly, single-step the asm in a debugger to see what's happening for yourself.  Or at least *post* the compiler-generate asm if you want other people to explain it for you.  There is no general-case answer. (I didn't downvote the question but the downvotes are fairly justified).    There's zero reason to expect the same stack layout in 2 functions.  In this case, it might have something to do with aligning the stack for a `call` in f2, placing locals at different places.

Answer (score 4):

From C99 standard (Section 6.7.8 Initialization): "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate."

Comment: Yeah, but you should look at what the compiler generates. At least on Intel, the stack with the initialized values would not be touched and so the call of the second function would find the initialized stack values. Unless the compiler has inlined or eliminated unused variables. But with optimizations disabled, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

[C standard 6.3.2.1p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2):

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

The behavior is undefined if you read an uninitialized variable. The standard does not dictate what should happen when undefined behavior is invoked.

> of course I know that C\CPP generate garbage and it can be anything. I am talking about the assembly side, if you dont know assembly or dont know how stack works please dont answer.

If you want to study the assembly code, then add `-S` when you compile and you can see what the compiler produces. However, this may be different from compiler to compiler, from target to target, from version to version etc. If you want to know exactly how the compiler does this, then study the documentation for the compiler. Or the source code if it is available.

Exactly what's going on in this particular example is not very useful knowledge. Well, I guess you can use it for exploits, but not to build robust software.

Answer (score 2):

Everybody referencing the C standard is of course completely correct. However, on Intel with optimizations disabled, my VC2008 generates code in which the three uninitialized variables of `f2` are "folded" onto the initialized variables of `f1`:

```
void f1()
{
  push        ebp  
  mov         ebp,esp 
  sub         esp,4Ch
    int a=1, b=2, c=3;
  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],1 
  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],2 
  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],3 
  mov         esp,ebp 
  pop         ebp  
  ret              
};

void f2()
{
  push        ebp  
  mov         ebp,esp 
  sub         esp,4Ch 
    int a, b, c;
  mov         esp,ebp 
  pop         ebp  
  ret              
};
```

With the relevant assembly of the calls in main:

```
  call        f1
  call        f2
```

as you can see, since the stack is not touched between calls, and the stack layout is identical in the two functions, the values of the uninitialzed variables are "whatever is on the stack" on those posiions, which happen to be the same positions as the intialized variables of `f1` and so `f2` finds the values of `f1`.

If the OP's `f2` does not find these values, then his compiler generates something else, so: look at the assembly.

Comment: First, Thank you very much. I tagged "Assembly" and talked about the stack and still people answered me that "I cant predict the result". You are the first that answering the question as is. So as I expected the stack has no change but still GCC dosent give me 1,2,3 and in MCVS 2019 I cant compile becuse the error is "uninitialized local variable".

Comment: How do you know that " the stack is not touched between calls"? There could be an interrupt or the like.

Comment: @dmuir, you are right. That would destroy the stack. Hence "undefined behavior"! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: "uninitialized local variable" is a warning, not an error. And you should look at the assembly generated.